# NSURLConnection VS NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I created a new project today for iOS 9 and I got a message that NSURLConnection is deprecated.
Since I have developed a controller for handling all my relative network connections I need to rewrite.

With NSURLConnection I created a RequestController.m which was handling the requests and their delegates and it was returning the results to the VC.

For example:
RequestController.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Reachability.h"

//================

@protocol RequestControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)RequestControllerRequestSuccessful:(NSInteger)mode;
- (void)RequestControllerRequestFailedWithReason:(NSString*)reason;

@end

//=================



@interface RequestController : NSObject <NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate>{

    NSURLConnection *conn;
    NSArray *responseArray;
    NSMutableData *responseData;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <RequestControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property(nonatomic,copy)NSMutableArray *resultArray;

-(id)initAndRegisterUserWithTelephone:(NSString*)tel Delegate:(id<RequestControllerDelegate>)del;

@end
```

RequestController.m

```
#import "RequestController.h"
#import "EnumConstants.h"

//We use MACRO to keep the URL. In the future when we will have more than 1 request we can change the URL for all requests from here.
#define API_URL @"http://asite.com"

//This class is a data controller which means that all requests on webservices should be here. We user enum to identify which request is calling this controller
RequestMode currentMode;


@implementation RequestController
@synthesize delegate,resultArray;

#pragma mark - Init Functions
-(id)initAndRegisterUserWithTelephone:(NSString*)tel Delegate:(id<RequestControllerDelegate>)del{

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        currentMode=AllDataMode;

        self.delegate=del;

        //Check for internet connection
        bool internet = [self internetConnectivity];

        //Sending the requests on the server
        if(internet){

            NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/gateway/mobile/service.cfc",API_URL];

            NSLog(@"url %@",url);

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:3];
            NSString *param= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"method=service&tel=%@",tel];


            NSData *requestBodyData = [param dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

            // Specify that it will be a POST request
            request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

            //conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];



            [conn start];
        }

        else
        {

            //No internet connection
            [delegate RequestControllerRequestFailedWithReason:@"Failed"];

        }



    }
    return self;

}
#pragma mark - Delegates for NSURLConnection
- (void):(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    // A response has been received, this is where we initialize the instance var you created
    // so that we can append data to it in the didReceiveData method
    // Furthermore, this method is called each time there is a redirect so reinitializing it
    // also serves to clear it
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;

    NSInteger code = [httpResponse statusCode];

    if (code!=200) {

        [delegate RequestControllerRequestFailedWithReason:@"Failed"];

        [connection cancel];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // Append the new data to the instance variable you declared

    [responseData appendData:data];


   NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
    //In some cases the API returns this error

}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    [connection cancel];

    if (currentMode==AllDataMode) {
        [self parseForGetALL:currentMode];

    }
    else{
        [self parseJSONFor:currentMode];

    }
    //Request has finished successfuly

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [delegate RequestControllerRequestFailedWithReason:@"Failed"];

}

#pragma mark - Parse method
-(void)parseForJSON:(NSInteger)mode{

    NSError *jsonParsingError=nil;

    //Converting the JSON data to a Dictionary
    NSDictionary *allDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonParsingError];

    if (jsonParsingError) {

        //In case the JSON is invalid we call the failed delegate
        [delegate RequestControllerRequestFailedWithReason:@"Failed"];

        return;
    }

    NSInteger comResponse = [[allDictionary objectForKey:@"compResponse"]integerValue];
    NSInteger catResponse = [[allDictionary objectForKey:@"catResponse"]integerValue];
    NSInteger locResponse = [[allDictionary objectForKey:@"locResponse"]integerValue];

    if (comResponse!=1 && catResponse!=1 && locResponse!=1) {

        [delegate RequestControllerRequestFailedWithReason:@"Failed"];
        return;
    }

    if (comResponse==1) {

        //Converting the "Companies"  object to an array so we can iterate and get all the values
        responseArray = [allDictionary objectForKey:@"companies"];

        compArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        for(NSDictionary *helperDict in responseArray){

          // Company *comp = [[Company alloc]initWithNSDictionary:helperDict];

           /// [compArray addObject:comp];

        }
    }


    [delegate RequestControllerRequestSuccessful:mode];

}

#pragma mark - Internet Connectivity method
//Check the internet connectivity
-(BOOL)internetConnectivity{

    Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {

        return FALSE;

    }
    else
    {

        return TRUE;

    }

}
```

My question is that how can I make the same controller for NSURLSession since it's singleton? It doesn't seems ok to me. Also I don't like either to call the NSURLSession from VC using blocks.
Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: u r using nsurlsession in the code!!! What is the problem ?

Comment: Sorry it was NSURLConnection and I tried to change it. The problem is the initialisation is different. NSURLConnection has alloc init and NSURLSession it's singleton. I am alloc/initing the controller for each request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All network connections should be done off the main thread...period.

`NSURLSession` is a block based API, so you will need to refactor to that, it's not that hard.

You can use `NSURLSession` in a pretty similar way.  I'm assuming that when you say

> Also I don't like either to call the NSURLSession from VC using blocks

You mean that you don't want to call `NSURLSession` specific APIs from your viewcontroller?  That's fine, you can totally encapsulate `NSURLSession` inside your `RequestController`.  Since it's a block based API though, I recommend updating the `RequestController` API to accept a block that may be passed in from the view controller which provides information on what to do when the request is complete.

Update RequestController.h with something like:

```
-(id)initAndRegisterUserWithTelephone:(NSString*)tel andSuccess:(void (^)())success andFailure:(void (^)())failure;
```

And then change RequestController.m with something like:

```
-(id)initAndRegisterUserWithTelephone:(NSString*)tel andSuccess:(void (^)())success andFailure:(void (^)())failure {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {

        currentMode=AllDataMode;

        //Check for internet connection
        bool internet = [self internetConnectivity];

        //Sending the requests on the server
        if(internet){

            NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/gateway/mobile/service.cfc",API_URL];

            NSLog(@"url %@",url);

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:3];
            NSString *param= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"method=service&tel=%@",tel];


            NSData *requestBodyData = [param dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

            // Specify that it will be a POST request
            request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

            NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                 fromData:requestBodyData 
                                        completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    failure();
                } else {
                    success();
                }
            }];

            [task resume];
        }

        else
        {

            //No internet connection
            [delegate RequestControllerRequestFailedWithReason:@"Failed"];

        }



    }
    return self;

}
```

Disclaimer: I didn't actually attempt to compile this code, so it may not be copy/paste perfect.

This tutorial on raywenderlich.com is very useful:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/67081/cookbook-using-nsurlsession

Comment: My worry is that NSURLSession is using some background threads instead of the main like NSURLConnection. Also I was using the delegates of NSURLConnections to handle all the requests (parse the data check the http code). If I use blocks I will need to rewrite them for each functions.

Comment: NSURLSession is a blocked based API so you'll need to refactor to use blocks, and absolutely don't do network calls on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. My point here is to centralise all the delegates from NSURLConnection. Should be bad practise to do that for NSURLSession also? Should I change the way am I thinking?

Comment: Not bad practice just a shift in mindset with a block based API.  NSURLSession is ultimately simpler than NSURLConnection.  You will need to rewrite some of that NSURLConnectionDelegate code though.

Answer (score 0):

You're relying on a delegate pattern with your current code, and so now you're going to have to call the NSURLSession method to create a 'task', and inside the block call the delegate from there. Everything should work fine.

```
- dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:
```

Then call the 'resume' method on the dataTask.

Comment: he's looking to upload data, not download it.  wrong api